# Подключение файлов. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: ооп, include, классы, php

В начале в файле index.php подключаем фаил конфигурации:

```
//Получение класса configuration из файла configuration.php
require_once(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  ."page".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."configuration.php");
```

в нем находится class и объект класса :

```
class configuration {  public $host = 'localhost';} 
$configuration = new configuration;
```

затем в файле index.php определяем класс для загрузки новых файлов:

```
class OpenPages {  
...
//функция определения страницы
        public function page ($file_open)   { 
                    include_once $file_open;                    
                } 
...}
```

создаем объект

```
$pageO = new OpenPages;
```

Подключаем фаил openvar.php

```
$pageO->page(openvar.php);
```

, который содержит код:

```
echo $configuration->host;
```

и надеемся увидить на экране 'localhost'. А в замен получаем ошибку:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.

Т.е. класс OpenPages "изолировал" от себя подключенный в начале класс configuration. 
Что делать? Выход только через return или есть более элегантное решение? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openvar.php` подключается в контексте метода `page()`, в котором никакого `$configuration` не существует. Ваш [капитан](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogCN3.jpg).

Comment: Я это понимаю, но что как сделать чтобы существовал?

Comment: @Максим147 объявить внутри метода `page()`, нет?

Comment: большое спасибо. Получилось, но необходимо чтобы класс configuration распросранялся полностью на класс OpenPages. Фаил configuration.php необходимо вставлять в каждую функцию или можно проще, я так понимаю если его вставить в 

public function __construct()
        {       include_once (getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."page".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."configuration.php"); 
       }  

это ничего не даст?

Comment: @Максим147

    class OpenPages
    {
        public $configuration;
        public function __construct($configuration)
        {
            $this->configuration = $configuration;
        }
        public function page($filepath)
        {
            $configuration = $this->configuration;
            include $filepath;
        }
    }
    $pageManager = new OpenPages(new configuration);
    $pageManager->page('somepage.php');

А вообще посмотрите, как в Yii рендерят страницы.